# Get values between a string and a char c#

Tags: c#, string

I have a string that looks like this:

`{"data":"key=IAfpK, age=58, key=WNVdi, age=64,`
and ends with `, age=48, key=dkSlj, age=5"}`

All I am trying to do is split this string into a string array and all I want is the numbers after age= to be inserted. And I need to handle the edge case at the end.

I was trying something like this:
`string [] ages = str.Split("age=", ",");` but you can't do that with strings, just chars.

Edit: the whole json is the following:

```json
{"data":"key=IAfpK, age=58, key=WNVdi, age=64, key=jp9zt, age=47, key=0Sr4C, age=68, key=CGEqo, age=76, key=IxKVQ, age=79, key=eD221, age=29, key=XZbHV, age=32, key=k1SN5, age=88, key=4SCsU, age=65, key=q3kG6, age=33, key=MGQpf, age=13, key=Kj6xW, age=14, key=tg2VM, age=30, key=WSnCU, age=24, key=f1Vvz, age=46, key=dOS7A, age=72, key=tDojg, age=82, key=nZyJA, age=48, key=R8JTk, age=29, key=005Ot, age=66, key=HHROm, age=12, key=5yzG8, age=51, key=xMJ5D, age=38, key=TXtVu, age=82, key=Hz38B, age=84, key=WfObU, age=27, key=mmqYB, age=14, key=4Z3Ay, age=62, key=x3B0i, age=55, key=QCiQB, age=72, key=zGtmR, age=66, key=nlIN9, age=8, key=hKalB, age=50, key=Na33O, age=17, key=jMeXm, age=15, key=OO2Mc, age=32, key=hhowx, age=34, key=gLMJf, age=60, key=PblX6, age=66, key=8Vm5W, age=22, key=oZKd6, age=88, key=RXNfQ, age=25, key=3yy0p, age=64, key=FrQbL, age=80, key=vlUkk, age=55, key=DP8po, age=80, key=EroX6, age=84, key=3bsll, age=86, key=QhZjA, age=85, key=wm6uc, age=74, key=MC1FM, age=75, key=AMxZr, age=64, key=ee03Q, age=4, key=9fGea, age=41, key=3TE9U, age=74, key=FoSMR, age=13, key=4To0X, age=57, key=5CZY3, age=33, key=qFvKG, age=79, key=W7bUh, age=2, key=htab7, age=15, key=KRyu2, age=77, key=GLkk7, age=80, key=jnXf6, age=51, key=YBTJ9, age=43, key=auL0J, age=30, key=ZHmmd, age=4, key=01iNV, age=7, key=7ldyh, age=55, key=TjXbT, age=88, key=ochyW, age=3, key=lsGXW, age=1, key=5o7Bd, age=45, key=APWEf, age=79, key=LRmKc, age=81, key=uZIoQ, age=12, key=Zf79H, age=42, key=NrpEI, age=6, key=XzYKx, age=22, key=kk0sU, age=62, key=p5uue, age=74, key=WscQQ, age=75, key=tRogh, age=19, key=ur4rW, age=60, key=IkCeS, age=19, key=vtGK4, age=11, key=C87cQ, age=38, key=0qXDb, age=39, key=KtBjN, age=46, key=f2h36, age=3, key=tGzgU, age=38, key=hIrPv, age=0, key=Tq7IX, age=25, key=F4k9K, age=46, key=9duxK, age=17, key=jTHDj, age=68, key=6GHpE, age=1, key=ye9us, age=9, key=eOfZO, age=72, key=I25vO, age=88, key=nqtBH, age=38, key=Dwn6b, age=70, key=4Qkdc, age=37, key=xvOa3, age=77, key=dg4rX, age=30, key=S9YbW, age=73, key=WhQqH, age=22, key=fexMF, age=88, key=Gzr0n, age=16, key=yFfjA, age=73, key=EfAKS, age=88, key=5Enyf, age=12, key=DK3HU, age=25, key=iGEBf, age=13, key=7r5UR, age=27, key=TQx1J, age=33, key=VlFwT, age=26, key=gnEgG, age=10, key=6P8gz, age=3, key=JnQLt, age=14, key=D3WJv, age=58, key=EXPMD, age=66, key=RzIDx, age=17, key=m6oYq, age=46, key=XTKAk, age=78, key=ZPLrJ, age=33, key=pDktp, age=10, key=TE9BG, age=18, key=7IS0l, age=35, key=yMY5X, age=58, key=jniwe, age=29, key=eb7lG, age=6, key=uzaoH, age=2, key=pUQoE, age=64, key=JZcuo, age=20, key=XwKBi, age=73, key=Zv4q9, age=31, key=HMD5T, age=76, key=rA4bI, age=75, key=PAMR7, age=86, key=tb8mz, age=2, key=vPcXk, age=18, key=c0Ixk, age=5, key=nkRrD, age=63, key=ISzFh, age=7, key=kcC1y, age=71, key=6J0WQ, age=27, key=FgiVY, age=72, key=Z8M30, age=50, key=Ep2Br, age=48, key=w9MRR, age=1, key=GI7oe, age=49, key=3ehsB, age=67, key=UW3dX, age=87, key=094dk, age=64, key=6tW4g, age=83, key=dT9IK, age=39, key=AofBp, age=27, key=7flGb, age=71, key=IBDqH, age=18, key=K2qn9, age=60, key=Qe7YJ, age=13, key=jqCHl, age=1, key=3R2IN, age=1, key=oVzfV, age=22, key=3yGCN, age=47, key=DOMm4, age=89, key=7EFRj, age=33, key=t1qsV, age=39, key=CBal1, age=14, key=BC0vr, age=68, key=0yY6L, age=47, key=Z8kX8, age=62, key=5oH1d, age=66, key=w0r3A, age=6, key=Bu8uK, age=55, key=vyqhK, age=35, key=7Zgz6, age=58, key=T573t, age=18, key=Rr4WR, age=48, key=kxnBU, age=39, key=XI3Jo, age=45, key=IAE95, age=43, key=rfSBT, age=59, key=znDPW, age=57, key=mBDDN, age=4, key=2hL0t, age=35, key=MbHM6, age=33, key=bS5oR, age=88, key=Rav2A, age=24, key=aLQO7, age=74, key=QCTUi, age=81, key=0HZlb, age=39, key=zshkO, age=5, key=q5EUd, age=75, key=WwgjN, age=20, key=LzTMa, age=3, key=uumoL, age=32, key=m3LJI, age=80, key=rU10P, age=39, key=gVTQz, age=79, key=wZjna, age=47, key=3d1E0, age=77, key=Ra74M, age=89, key=FJXHG, age=11, key=MckmR, age=37, key=tSqfN, age=2, key=HHkpI, age=40, key=S7rIA, age=34, key=vnpjJ, age=2, key=t8WSa, age=84, key=38fyp, age=11, key=Znot2, age=72, key=OGqoG, age=65, key=7VKiL, age=58, key=UdlEG, age=79, key=BXxIS, age=47, key=eW6F8, age=10, key=GASTN, age=86, key=SP0yy, age=53, key=ysN9w, age=17, key=KVGGz, age=76, key=yhEVk, age=47, key=vvlgV, age=67, key=aIMuS, age=21, key=KcHZk, age=41, key=6n8pa, age=35, key=ADTut, age=3, key=WNJXO, age=37, key=qta1A, age=67, key=cJOTp, age=67, key=1Bgd3, age=71, key=sHepZ, age=67, key=JoMvH, age=65, key=h1gF0, age=53, key=we7hP, age=41, key=Ztl8x, age=8, key=7pkQj, age=43, key=fkBah, age=21, key=FWETS, age=55, key=Gb4IY, age=26, key=U88H6, age=57, key=iExWE, age=8, key=7sl6v, age=8, key=iwI1x, age=9, key=cdKUG, age=60, key=xb127, age=57, key=dqYi8, age=15, key=opO2h, age=80, key=RNux0, age=37, key=cooLT, age=7, key=qhzQn, age=18, key=uowal, age=10, key=YR8Oy, age=17, key=GwEwr, age=15, key=WIXKE, age=53, key=aeem8, age=88, key=UPYoP, age=85, key=IF1pO, age=11, key=R6pUy, age=37, key=vYADh, age=0, key=TIq4k, age=35, key=dCekr, age=56, key=HBbXO, age=84, key=Lo9h5, age=36, key=fqBW3, age=87, key=OQWCL, age=52, key=nlYrf, age=6, key=cUS5f, age=32, key=A5gR0, age=32, key=HpUXl, age=84, key=nOuUT, age=18, key=mfvjr, age=12, key=24FH4, age=13, key=2rQei, age=51, key=EGAAV, age=8, key=Q5ifr, age=50, key=AVpil, age=87, key=vRcjt, age=51, key=G53C3, age=53, key=bsZAz, age=66, key=a8rVi, age=28, key=qPs5m, age=48, key=hF1kt, age=78, key=GIDFA, age=32, key=d2Mg4, age=12, key=EoYwt, age=30, key=DL7zx, age=14, key=lsA6c, age=17, key=ExutD, age=82, key=YOSNP, age=53, key=PEfma, age=49, key=EA8Go, age=18, key=fGTSM, age=60, key=lRf1j, age=13, key=0iJGV, age=50, key=cFCfU, age=5, key=J8an1, age=48, key=dkSlj, age=5"}
```

Comment: Try 2 steps after splitting on ":"; split on "," then take those elements that start "age=" and extract the following value for each. The character you split on is the `char`. See [this definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split)

Comment: It looks like malformed json to be honest, `key` and `age` would be a composite object. So you'd have an array of key/age objects. How is this string created?

Comment: @zaggler it is a json, but I was having trouble parsing the JSON so I thought that just grabbing the ages (which is what I need) would be easy enough

Comment: @user2007843 no don't do that, post your json, I'll show you how it can be done. Anyways you should create objects that represent your json and deserialize to it.

Comment: @zaggler okay its posted

Comment: @zaggler https://coderbyte.com/api/challenges/json/age-counting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a pattern with a capture group to match `age=` and capture 1 or more digits `([0-9]+)`

```
\bage=([0-9]+)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T9JAp8/1)

For example:

```
string input = @"{""data"":""key=IAfpK, age=58, key=WNVdi, age=64, and ends with , age=48, key=dkSlj, age=5""}";
String[] matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"\bage=([0-9]+)")
           .Cast<Match>()
           .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
           .ToArray();
Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", string.Join(", ", matches));
```

Output

```
[58, 64, 48, 5]
```

For the updated example data, you could also parse the json and get the data property.

Assuming the data always has the format as in the example:

```
string input = @"...";
input = JObject.Parse(input).SelectToken("data").Value<string>(); 

var result = input.Split(", ").Aggregate(
    new List<String>(), (a,c) => {
        if(c.StartsWith("age=")) {
            a.Add(c.Split("=")[1]);
        } 
        return a;
    });
    
Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", string.Join(", ", result));
```

Output

```
[58, 64, 47, 68, 76, 79, 29, 32, 88,.....
```

Comment: And, if you want, you can capture the keys as well.  Do this by making a regex that includes the two patterns.  At that point, each of your matches will include the two values

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a JSON result and this is from an API method
you should delete the "data" at the begining of your result.
Create a struct contains key as a property and value as a 2nd property  .
After that you can use JSON.deserializeObject

Finally you have list of object and you Use  any linq method